# How many days it takes to verify/review my Google developers students club lead application form

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-platform

I've registered for a GDSC lead couple of days ago, I'm so curious about reply mail from them.

Does any one know about the verifying/review process of GDSC lead application.

Answer (score 0):

Around 15 to 20 days and sometimes within a week and more than 20 days usually depend on the traffic of application forms from your university.